# Best-First Search evaluation function

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, evaluation

I'm implementing Best-First Search algorithm in C#. This is Console Application.

Data structure which I use is a tree. Evaluation function I saw in this algorithm was straight-line distance between two nodes (e.g. cities). Distance was a vector (length) on a grid in graphical application. My app is in console, so I can't calculate vectors between nodes.

How can I calculate evaluation function in my way of implementation this algorithm?

**EDIT (based on @Andrew's idea)**

I drew a tree on a piece of paper and I assigned the coordinates to nodes. 
Start point is A (root). End point is L (user choose the goal in program). 
Distance is calculated by euclidean formula for two dimensions:

```
d(p,q) = sqrt(pow((p1 - q1), 2) + pow((p2 - q2), 2))
```

Look at the picture: [Best-First Search for Tree](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23235541/Scan_20141211_134124.png)

Is it a good idea?

Comment: I have not tried to calculate this eval function yet because I do not have idea for this. Any idea?

Comment: You don't need UI to calculate distance. Search for math (or ready-made peace of code/library) first (this is called effort). If you have difficulties with code then you have a good reason to ask for help here. I can find math in 3 sec, you?

Comment: But my tree represantation is a matrix nxn (adjacency matrix). I am creating a tree with Dictionary and then apply keys and values to matrix. How can I calculate this function?

Answer (score 1):

For the evaluation function you need to have an equation of the line that goes through two points:

The equation of the line passing through two different points P_0 = ( x_0, y_0 ) and P_1 = (x_1, y_1) may be written as

```
(y - y_0)(x_1 - x_0) = (y_1 - y_0)(x - x_0).
```

Next to it, your node should belong to this line.

That is the node with coordinates (x*, y*) should satisfy the equation :

```
(y* - y_0)(x_1 - x_0) = (y_1 - y_0)(x* - x_0)
```

If the two parts of the equation evaluate to different values, your node(point(x*,y*)) is not on the straight line between the required points(cities)

Comment: I think that TSP is not related with Best-First Search. In B-F Search we use evaluation function as heuristic. Btw. I will implement later Simulated Annealing for TSP problem. But first I must do Best-First Search.

Comment: ok, if the question is about evaluation function then you need a line that passes through your start and end node

Comment: Hmm, it makes sense. So, I must add location coordinates for every node - but how apply coordinates for node if it is console app? My representation is adjacency matrix for the tree.

Comment: Use a custom class for the node element, having coordinates among the class properties. You may also consider looking into 'Point' structure of `System.Drawing` namespace...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Okay, I updated original post with "Edit". Please look at "Edit section".

Comment: I thought you need to find nodes on the same line between starting and end points.

Comment: Sorry @Andrew, my English is not the best. Can you explain your idea easier to make it understand for me?

Comment: Now it looks like among all possible paths between `A` and `L`  you need to find the one that is more smooth. For Each such a path I'd calculate distance between the point on the path and the line A-L. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line. Calculate total value for all points..and compare the paths.(I.E.you may have one city that is 5 km from straight line in your path.and you may have 2 cities that are 4 km from the straight line each in different directions.First route is smoother then)

Comment: Ideally you'd need to calculate surface area of the polynomial that passes through the cities(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) against the line that joins A and L

Comment: something like a integral of module of two functions `d(|(lagrange polynomial) - (A-L)line|)/dx from A to L`. the bigger the value the less smooth it is

Comment: `d(|(subfunctions between each point) - (A-L)line|)/dx from A to L` is a bit more simple